# How can I connect vertica with JDBC?

Tags: netbeans, jdbc, vertica

I want to connect Vertica with JDBC. But I got errors.
Here is my code:

....

```
 Class.forName("com.vertica.jdbc.Driver");
```

....

```
 connection= DriverManager.getConnection
             (
             "jdbc:vertica://192.168.2.116:5433/schema", "dbadmin", "pass123"
             );
```

But I got this error (if I open the NetBeans database section, I got the same error message. But I connect to Vertica with the client ([DBeaver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBeaver))):

> ex = (java.sql.SQLException) java.sql.SQLException: [Vertica] No enum const class com.vertica.dsi.dataengine.utilities.MetadataSourceColumnTag.COLUMN_SİZE

How can I fix this?

Comment: its about 32 bit  - 64 bit issue I think, because it is working on 32 bit windows I cant understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because of your locale. In this case Turkish, I guess.

COLUMN_SİZE has upper case i → İ.

It is Vertica's fault to use toUpper digressively.

Comment: yes you are right, When I install the application I should choose the english language

Comment: *[digressively](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/digressively#Adverb)* is not a commonly-used word. Do you really mean that?

Answer (score 2):

So if you need a JDBC client for Vertica in NetBeans or [IntelliJ IDEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA), use [this Vertica JDBC driver](http://www.dbschema.com/jdbc-drivers/VerticaJdbcDriver.zip).  It's the one that worked for me (taken from `dbvisuzlizer`).

Comment: "dbvisuzlizer" looks like a typo ("`A`" → "`Z`"). "dbvisualizer"?

Answer (score 1):

Vertica's connect string uses databasename, not schema name after the host:port.  See the doc for details:

https://my.vertica.com/docs/CE/6.0.1/HTML/index.htm#1395.htm

Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
    "jdbc:vertica://VerticaHost:portNumber/databaseName", 
    "username", "password");

By default, users have a search path of "$user, public, v_catalog, v_monitor and v_internal", therefore, you can create and use a matching username to connect directly to the desired SCHEMA.

Answer (score 0):

It’s about a 32 bit - 64 bit issue I think, because it is working on 32 bit Windows. I can’t understand.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the connector (*vertica-jdbc-xxxx.jar*) is in the *JDK\jre\lib\ext* folder.